# Play! and Spark incompatible Jackson versions

Tags: apache-spark, playframework, sbt

I have a problem running Spark 2.1 with Play! 2.5.9.

I get the following runtime exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.6
```

In the previous version of Spark (1.6), I managed to suppress this error adding in my `build.sbt` file:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Set("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.4")
```

But it doesn't work with Spark 2. I tried to change the version used in `dependencyOverrides` by 2.7.2 and 2.8.5, but I have no idea of which one I should use and why.

Any clue would be very appreciated ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using a version 2.6.x in dependencyOverrides works (I still don't know if there is an other way to find a version that works than testing one after an other).

Comment: To find the correct version, lookup the version of Spark on maven repo, then look at that version's dependencies. Use the version of Jackson listed there (it is 2.6.5 for Spark 2.1.1 according to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0 )

Comment: Thanks Tayler. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with Spark 2.4.0. The dependency override that worked for me is:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.8"
```

I believe the same override works for 2.4.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `Spark 2.4.4` and `play-json 2.8.1`, so looked for the Spark dependencies in maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.12/2.4.4 ; where I can see the version of `jackson-databind` that I need. Finally I've added the following line to my `build.sbt` file:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.7.1"
```

This means play-json is now using an older version of `jackson-databind` which I don't really like, but it's working for me.